# MS Access 2007 - Show values rather than looked up data in a table

Tags: database, ms-access

Wow, I'm having a bit of a headache with Access 2007.  I have two tables, main_table and ref_table.  when I store an int id in main_table corresponding to some record in ref_table, I get the looked up value of the record that I'm storing and not the int id.  This isn't what I expected and I'd like access to behave like every other database on the face of the planet and show me the information how I stored it and not how it thinks I want to see it.  Anyone know how to turn this 'feature' off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.
1-Go to design view of your table.
2-select the look-up tab bellow the field list.
3-Change row source type to "values".